# Magento 2 : Hide payment method from checkout method list

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

I have created a custom offline payment method, which I want to be visible through API, but not during web checkout.

I tried with `<can_use_checkout>0</can_use_checkout>` in config.xml, but it affects API as well.

I have found the source of the payment list in this file,
`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/payment-methods/list.html` , but unsure how to hide a specific payment method from here.

Comment: you want to hide it for frontend only ?

Comment: @Pawan Yes, it would appear everywhere else. Just hidden for the customer placing order using web.

Comment: create a plugin for `getAvailableMethods`. refer https://github.com/pawan/adminenablepayments/blob/master/Plugin/Model/Method/Available.php

Comment: @Pawan Won't this disable the method from API calls as well ?

Comment: it shouldn't if you put di.xml in front end folder

Answer (score 0):

**Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml**

```
<event name="payment_method_is_active">
     <observer name="disable_paymentMethods" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\ObserverforDisabledFrontendPaymentMethods" />
</event>
```

**Vendor\Module\Observer\ObserverforDisabledFrontendPaymentMethods.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\App\State;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class ObserverforDisabledFrontendPaymentMethods implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var State
     */
    protected $_appState;

    /**
     * ObserverDisabledFrontendPg constructor.
     * @param State $appState
     */
    public function __construct(
        State $appState
    ) {
        $this->_appState = $appState;
    }

    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
        $methodInstance = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();

        if (null !== $quote) {
            $methodCode = $methodInstance->getCode();
            //Chnage with your method name
            if ($methodCode == "payment_name" && $this->_appState->getAreaCode() == "frontend")
            {
                $result->setData('is_available', false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I will try this out.

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately. The custom payment method is getting removed from `V1/carts/mine/shipping-information` as well.

Comment: Print the AreaCode when you use the API.

Comment: check which area code you get when execute the API

Comment: I tried , and for both cases (API and frontend) it shows `webapi_rest`

Comment: You change that payment_name with your payment method ?

Comment: Yes I did. Here is my code  `if (null !== $quote) {
    $methodCode = $methodInstance->getCode();
    if ($methodCode == "phonepepayment" && $this->_appState->getAreaCode() == \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND)
    {
        $result->setData('is_available', false);
    }
}`

Comment: can you make sure that your payment metho code is correct.